((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER)) throws NullPointerException in Appium
I am getting NullPointerException on executing ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
Using Appium v9.3.0
It was working few days back, not sure what exactly happened but it stopped working now.
Can someone please help me?
Tried with different versions of appium
